# Classifier: output wrong

Tags: pandas, classification

I have dataframe looks like this:

```
df
Annotation_A    Annotation_B
first           Boarding
first           Alighting
last            Boarding
last            Alighting
first           Boarding
first           Alighting
last            Alighting
```

I analyzed the data with this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
def classifier(row):
    if row["Annotation_A"] == "first" and row["Annotation_B"] == "Boarding":
        return "match-1"
    elif row["Annotation_A"] == "last" and row["Annotation_B"] == "Alighting":
        return "match-2"
    else:
        return "Un-match"
df["Matching"] = df.apply(classifier, axis=1)
```

I want to make a new column "match" which are containing "match-1 and match-2". However, I got wrong output looks like this:

```
Annotation_A    Annotation_B    Matching
first           Boarding        match-1
first           Alighting       Un-match
last            Boarding        Un-match
last            Alighting       Un-match -->must be "match-2"
first           Boarding        match-1
first           Alighting       Un-match
last            Alighting       Un-match -->must be "match-2"
```

Comment: Check if your data has trailing spaces, you should print what the values to see if there are spaces

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce your issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TMEj.png

Comment: maybe there is a space in my column data. how to remove the space?

Comment: I use this `df['Annotation_A'] = df['Annotation_A'].str.strip()` and `df['Annotation_B'] = df['Annotation_B'].str.strip()`